# Can I use WifiP2pmanager class ( API 14) in older API ( ex API 9)?

Tags: android

I'm trying to program an app to discover wifi devices which are connecting to an Access Point. I found that WifiP2pmanager class can be used to scan wifi devices but it's just for API14. Is there anyway to use this class in older API ?
(sorry for my poor English >.<)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use `WifiP2pmanager` on older API levels.

The only way would be to use the Android [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html), however it does not currently support `WifiP2pmanager`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately - NO...

WifiP2pManager is part of new API called WiFi-Direct , and is a knowned technology to generate an AdHoc connection between WiFi devices without a needed AP.

people waited a long time before Google supported this API.

Previous Versions are not supporting this API.